# ClientID problem when trying to override a control's Render event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using ASP.Net 2.0. I have a custom control that is inherits from a 3rd-party vendor's control. I'm trying to override the Render method.

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
 if (some condition is true) then    
   Dim d As New Button()    
   d.RenderControl(writer)    
 else    
   MyBase.Render(writer)    
 end if    
end sub
```

What I need is that under certain situations I want to be able to render a Button instead of the original control.
But I want the Button to have the same client Id as the control so that I can use javascript to manipulate it.

How do I assign a clientid to the button?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ClientID is based on the control's ID and UniqueID of its parent. When you create your button you should give it an ID. I don't see that happening in your code. After you Dim it, use `d.ID="btnIdNameHere"`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx):

> The ClientID value is generated by
>   concatenating the ID value of the
>   control and the UniqueID value of its
>   parent control. If the ID value of the
>   control is not specified, an
>   automatically generated value is used.

Comment: Using d.ID="btnIdNameHere" doesn't work for me because my control is in a panel. It can also be in multiple nested panels.
So when I create the button I can't seem to make it such that it is the same ID as my original control.